# European call option on constant volatility or drawn from a volatility distribution

Tags: options, volatility, european-options

Which is more expensive:

A European call option on constant volatility of 30% or or drawn from a random distribution of mean 30%?

The answer in A Practical Guide To Quantitative Finance Interviews, isnt very clear at all. The justification as to why stochastic volatility would make the price more or less expensive is not clear to me.

Comment: We don't know anything about the distribution of vol besides its mean, e.g. normality etc.? What explanation does the book give?

Comment: Would you be able to post the answer from the source? A screenshot / snap suffices. Just asking: Maybe there's some more in the question that you missed to post here.  @PontusHultkrantz's approach would be my way to go as well, and in an interview I would start to babble something about convexity in IV, conditions under Black Scholes and all that...

Comment: @Kermittfrog page 79 RHS, https://raw.githubusercontent.com/geniayuan/datasciencecoursera/master/%5BXinfeng%20Zhou%5DA%20practical%20Guide%20to%20quantitative%20finance%20interviews.pdf

Comment: @PontusHultkrantz see the above

Comment: @Trajan: thanks, then my current reasoning is correct, but it is pretty much identical to what they wrote. I can expand my answer, but would you clarify what is unclear with their answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) states that given a convex function $f(x)$ and random variable $X$ we have
$$ \mathbb{E}[f(X)] \geq  f(\mathbb{E}[X]). $$

Now $f$ is our call price, and $X$ is our random volatility with $\mathbb{E}[X]=\sigma_0$. The question now is, when is the call price convex in volatility?

Comment: I think that your ansatz is correct; *but* you need to carefully check under which conditions the option price is truly convex in the implied volatility parameter.

Comment: @Kermittfrog: Good point! You are right, If I got it correct, it is convex for $\sigma < \sqrt{2|\ln(S/K)|}$, which makes it complicated around this region.

Comment: @PontusHultkrantz could you explain your final question more, I dont get where you are pointing

Comment: @Trajan: I had to revert (edit) it and remove the last part of my answer, so not really a full answer yet. It is not obvious to me how to solve this in a nice way, especially since the spot price and strike might be such that the upper bound for convexity around 30%...